# How to fix the the error in migration when migrating in mysql in django

Tags: mysql, django, migration

When I'm trying to migrate my models in Django in MySQL. I always got this error

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'

I'm feeling it was version conflict on mysql and django

Attached is the error message I'm getting
[image]

Comment: can you add your model for which the error generate?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman thank you for the response, sir.  I'm not sure how to determine which model is responsible for the error

Comment: may be your are write several model and migrate these successfully. Later on you add a field or model then makemigrations error occurred.

Comment: I erased all the migration files and created a new database, still i received this error

Comment: No. Problem in model or model fields

Comment: what version of python you are using

Comment: @c.grey my python version is 3.4, my mysqlclient version is 1.4.2.post1 and my django version is 2.0.13

Comment: @michaelababao this version specific issue try upgrade sql version

Comment: It has some version issue on python 3.4. upgraded from 3.5 or higher and it works. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some browsing i found out that it has some version issue on python 3.4. Upgraded from python 3.5 or higher and it worked.